# Increment count during switch statements

Tags: java

I am creating HomeLoans and CarLoans for a loan system. Need to be able to create as many as the user wants. The switch statement is for the menu. My current problem is that when I create a homeloan and go back to the menu, and then create another one, it forces me to make 2 loans. I guess because of my Homecount++. Then when I view the loans, it only remembers the previous 2 and not the first one. How can I keep creating loans and adding them to the array, without losing data from going in and out of the switch statement?

```
public class TestingClasses {

private static Loan getInfo(Scanner scan, char c){

System.out.println("Please enter your Name: ");
String nameOf = scan.next();
System.out.println("Please enter an ID Number: ");
String id_Number = scan.next();
System.out.println("Please enter a Loan Number: ");
String loan_Number = scan.next();
System.out.println("Please enter the amount of the Loan: ");
double loan_Amount = scan.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Please enter your desired Interest Rate: ");
double interest_rate = scan.nextDouble();
while(interest_rate > 100.00){ //Check valid number
    System.out.println("Invalid percentage. Please enter 0.00 - 100.00");
    interest_rate = scan.nextDouble();
}
System.out.println("How long will you like the loan? Please enter 1-30.");
int term = scan.nextInt();
while(term > 30){ // Check for valid number
    System.out.println("Invalid number of years. Please enter 1-30.");
    term = scan.nextInt();
}
System.out.println("Current balance is being set to the Loan amount. \n");
double c_balance = loan_Amount;

if(c == 'H'){

    System.out.println("Please enter an address for the Home: ");
    String address = scan.next();

    return new HomeLoan(nameOf,id_Number,loan_Number,loan_Amount,
    interest_rate,term,c_balance,address);
}
if(c == 'C'){

    System.out.println("Please enter the Make of the car: ");
    String make = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter the Model of the car: ");
    String model = scan.next();
    System.out.println("Please enter the Year of the car: ");
    String year = scan.next();
    return new CarLoan(nameOf,id_Number,loan_Number,loan_Amount,
    interest_rate,term,c_balance,make,model,year);

}
else
    return null;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int CarCount=0,HomeCount = 0;
    int j = 0;
            HomeLoan HL[]=null;
    CarLoan CL[]=null;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int menuChoice = 0;
    char c;
            HL= new HomeLoan[60];

    String mainMenu = ("Select a choice from the menu: \n" 
            + "1. Create HomeLoan\n" 
            + "2. Create CarLoan\n"
            + "3. Make Payment\n" 
            + "4. Check Balances\n"
            + "5. List of HomeLoans\n" 
            + "6. List of CarLoans\n"
            + "7. Amortization Report\n"
            + "8. Exit");

    System.out.println("Welcome to the Loan system!  \n");

    do{
    System.out.println(mainMenu);
    menuChoice = scan.nextInt();

    while (menuChoice < 1 || menuChoice > 8) {
        System.out.print("\nError! Incorrect choice.\n");
        System.out.println(mainMenu);
        menuChoice = scan.nextInt();
    }


switch (menuChoice) {
    case 1: {

        c = 'H';
         // Add 1 to HomeCount


        for(; j == HomeCount; j++){

            HL[j]=(HomeLoan)getInfo(scan,c);
            System.out.println(HL[j].getHomeLoanNumber());
        }
            HomeCount++;
        break;
        }
    case 2: {

        c = 'C'; 
        CarCount++; // Add 1 to Car Count
        CL = new CarLoan[CarCount];

        for(int j = 0; j < CarCount; j++){ //Loop through loans

            CL[j]=(CarLoan)getInfo(scan,c);
            System.out.println(CL[j].getCarLoanNumber());
        }
        break;
    }
    case 5: {
        for(int k=0; k < HomeCount; k++){
            System.out.println(HL[k]+ "\n");
        }
        break;
    }
    }
    }while(menuChoice != 8); //ending do while loop
    }//end main
}//end class
```

Comment: Dunno if this changes anything, but case: doesn't need curly braces.

Comment: Original post edited with formatting of posted code. Original poster, please take care with your indentation of your code. Careless indentation leads to code that is difficult to read and then to careless errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you create a new array, you delete the previous array (well, it isn't deleted, but all references to it are lost, so it might as well have been deleted). A  better solution is to use an `ArrayList<Loan>` not an array, create it once *before your loop, and then simply add items to the List as needed. Think of an ArrayList as an array that can expand or shrink in size dynamically.

Otherwise if you *must* use arrays, then consider creating an array once when you declare it, and give it enough items when you create it, so that you don't run out of space.

Comment: Thanks, changed the array size to a value and changed the looping. Works now. Editing code above with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You keep reassigning a new array into `HL` and `CL` inside the switch every time you come there. Thus it only remembers the loans from the last iteration.